# How to execute a *.bat file on a remote computer using psexec.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, psexec

1. I have two computers one running Windows 8.1 Pro and the other running Windows 10 Pro (remote computer).
2. The windows 10 computer has a *.bat file located in the following path "c:\windows\shutdown.bat".
3. I want to be able to execute the shutdown.bat file on the remote computer from a command prompt on the Windows 8.1 computer.
4. I've tried the following command from the Windows 8.1 (computer) command prompt `psexec -u username -p ***** -i \\DESKTOP-P c:\windows\shutdown.bat`
5. Lastly on the Windows 10 computer the Windows Defender Firewall is disabled.

But I get the following error in the command window on the Windows 8.1 computer.

```
Couldn't access DESKTOP-P:
Access is denied.
```

Can anyone help me in determine what is going wrong with the above command?

Comment: You don't have privileges to access `\\DESKTOP-P`

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you. But can you explain how to add privileges ?